# How to use word winsome?

Tags: word-usage

"Your rain  of love
Turned the land of my barren heart
Into a valley full of winsome flowers"
Can I use winsome here? If not then suggest me some words that I can use with flower
And please let me know if there is any other grammatical mistakes.

Comment: "Winsome" is fine.  Do a Google search of "winsome flowers."  You will find thousands of examples where people have described flowers as "winsome."

Comment: @Billy can you suggest me some other word that would look more effective with flower?

Comment: The most common way to use _winsome_ is **not** to use it. For a poem, it’s fine; in normal conversation, you’d be quite unlikely to hear it from a native speaker.

Comment: What, specifically, is wrong with *winsome*? No other word can be reasonably proposed unless we know your criteria.

Answer (score -1):

Your use of **winsome** in your sentence is fine.  Other synonyms of winsome [TDF](http://attractive%20bewitching%20enchanting%20engaging%20enticing%20fascinating%20fetching%20glamorous%20lovely%20prepossessing%20pretty%20sweet%20taking%20tempting%20winning):

attractive
bewitching
enchanting
engaging
enticing
fascinating
fetching
glamorous
lovely
prepossessing
pretty
sweet
taking
tempting
winning